# How to get a Castle Windsor factory facility created instance to still have constructor injection?

Tags: castle-windsor, constructor-injection, typed-factory-facility

I am a bit new to factory facility, so please bear with me if what I am doing is daft.
Heres my container registration:

```
_container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());

_container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
_container.Register(Component
    .For<ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>()
    .ImplementedBy<CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector>());

_container.Register(
    Component.For<ICalcService>()
        .ImplementedBy<CalcService>()
        .Named("Base")
        .LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<ICalcService>()
        .ImplementedBy<AverageCalcService>()
        .Named("Average")
        .LifeStyle.Transient,
    Component.For<ICalcServiceFactory>()
        .AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith(new CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector())));

_container.Register(
    Component.For<IEventAggregator>()
        .ImplementedBy<EventAggregator>()
        .LifeStyle.Singleton);
```

Then I resolve from the factory (I build lots of these read in from config, hence create by text string)

```
_factory = _container.Resolve<ICalcServiceFactory>();
var averageCalc = _factory.GetByType("Average");
```

(for instance)

What I'm stumped with is this: If I try to give all my calculation objects a base instance like this:

```
public abstract class BaseCalcService : ICalcService
{
    protected readonly IEventAggregator EventAggregator;
    public BaseCalcService(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        EventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }
...
```

and derive like this

```
public class AverageCalcService : BaseCalcService
{
    public AverageCalcService(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : base(eventAggregator)
    {
    }
    ...
```

then CW barfs over the lack of a default constructor.

Question: How do I set up factory facility to allow injection (automatic) of the EventAggregator instance, when I use the factory to build the calc object?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: Here's my CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector:

```
public class CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector  
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        if (method.Name == "GetByType" && arguments.Length == 1 && arguments[0] is string)
        {
            return (string)arguments[0];
        }
        return base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
    }
```

### }

Edit: Heres the EventAggregator. Nothing special.

Interface

```
public interface IEventAggregator
{
    void SendMessage<T>(T message) where T : IEvent;
    void SendMessage<T>() where T : IEvent, new();
    void AddListener(IListenTo listener);
    void RemoveListener(IListenTo listener);
}
```

And the ctor

```
public EventAggregator(SynchronizationContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what your CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector looks like?  By default the DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector will use methods that start with Get (i.e. GetXXX) will look for components that are named with the value after Get (i.e. XXX).

Comment: Added CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector. Thx.

Comment: The Selector looks fine, what about the EventAggregator implemenation?  What does it constructor(s) look like?

Comment: Hi, I altered the EventAggregator to no longer have a SynchronizationContext and it all works. As I'm dropping the EventAggregator in favour of a simpler Publisher based around Reactive Extensions this should work.
THANKS all for responses!

Comment: There are ways to still get the SynchronizationContext injected, if you are still interested let me know.

Comment: Sure Chris, always interested to learn!